# Search a nested array and return the parent array?

Tags: php

```
$array = [
    [
        'name' => 'john',
        'age' => 25
        'children' => [
            'jane',
            'jeff',
        ],
    ],
    ....
];
```

I wish to get the entire sub array depending on a value in a nested array, for example, I can do...

```
array_search('john', array_column($array, 'name')); // 0
```

But how can I do the same for the `children` sub array, for example, I want to find the `john` multidimensional array by searching for a child's name, e.g. `jeff`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the array_search function alone will probably not be enough. The combination array_search and array_filter would help you

```
array_filter($array, function($value) {
   return ($value['name'] === 'john' && in_array('jeff', $value['children']));
});
```